# how to turn lock screen on for a scheduled status bar notification without using deprecated wake locks?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am using alarm manager to schedule status bar notifications. There is no problem when screen is on and phone is unlocked. But when phone is locked and screen is turned off how can I turn it on when a notification comes. As full wake lock, screen bright and screen dim wake locks are deprecated. So what is the best alternative to turn screen on. I know FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON but it does not turn screen on for a status bar notification. Please help me. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can not turn on the screen for the status bar notifications. Instead of this you can push one transparent activity at that time so the screen will be turned on.

Comment: thank u. i did the same. but my notification appears twice. I am creating notification in my transparent activity onResume method. any suggestion plz?

Comment: Outstanding! it worked perfectly. Thank u very much. I dont have enough points to upvote and sorry for that.